# Nextflow channel conversion

Tags: channel, nextflow

I would line to convert a channel that emits this:

```
[A,[1,2,3]] 
[B,[4,5,6]]
```

to a channel emitting this:

```
[A,1] 
[A,2] 
[A,3] 
[B,4] 
[B,5] 
[B,6]
```

I am pretty sure there is something "kind of" straightforward to do it but I've been struggling since yesterday on it.

Answer (score 1):

So ... I found the transpose() operator which does exactly that.

https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/operator.html#transpose

Thank you all for your help.